# how to generate form and text from string using knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a string like this :

`var par = 'hello my name is @firstname.'`

with knockout js i want to generate this string to a form and text, may be like this :

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:firstname" />

<p>
hello my name is <span data-bind="text:firstname"></span>.
</p>
```

so `@firstname` will generate an input with value firstname, and every update on firstname will update the paragraph.

i create a jsfiddle to testing :
https://jsfiddle.net/yozawiratama/rmsuc5uv/

but still not work, because still hardcoded
thanks

Comment: In your viewmodel you are not using **firstname**, so what you are trying to do?

Comment: Why bothering with the regex anyway? Is this https://jsfiddle.net/rmsuc5uv/5/ what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: regex to read [at]firstname in 'hello my name is [at]firstname.' a text with symbol [at]

Comment: 'with knockout js i want to generate this string to a form and text'

Comment: Still, what you are trying to do? Textbox where user types in, what you want to do with the user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a pretty interesting problem, and you had got it pretty much solved. The only thing is, you were changing `par`, so that after the first substitution, it didn't contain your variable anymore. Instead, work on a copy of the original within the computed, and return that copy.

```js
var par = 'hello my name is @firstname.'
var pattern = /\B@[a-z0-9_-]+/gi;
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.firstname = ko.observable("yoza");
  self.defaultParagraph = ko.observable(par);
  self.paragraph = ko.computed(function() {
    var p = self.defaultParagraph().match(pattern); //to get @firstname
    var newPar = par;
    for (var ii = 0; ii < p.length; ii++) {
      var re = new RegExp(p[ii], 'g'),
          replacement = self[p[ii].replace('@', '')]();

      newPar = newPar.replace(re, replacement);
    }
    return newPar;
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value:firstname" />

<p data-bind="text:paragraph">
</p>
```

For a more general case, where you don't know going in what your variable might be, you'd want a custom binding handler that binds an empty object. The `init` section would create observables within that object and create the DOM elements, and call the binding. The `update` section would be something like your `computed`.

Comment: thank you very much, i really waiting someone like you.